# Sandbox Source Tracking does not activate

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, source-tracking

I have enabled source tracking in Developer and Developer Pro sandboxes in the production org, but source tracking commands still throw an error even after a sandbox refresh.

Some details: we have a master sandbox(developer) with some test data already created and we refresh/create our sandboxes from it. After I activated the Source Tracking in Dev and Dev Pro Sandboxes, I refreshed my sandbox from the master sandbox(both are developer sandboxes), re-authorized the org in my VSC and also restarted VSC, but I am still getting the error when I try to reset the tracking:

```
PS C:\Users\Novarg\Documents\VSCode\salesforce-sfdx> sfdx force:source:tracking:reset
WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at "56.0"
WARNING: This operation will modify all your local source tracking files. The operation can have unintended consequences on all the force:source commands. Are you sure you want to proceed (y/n)?: y
ERROR running force:source:tracking:reset:  This command can only be used on orgs that have source tracking enabled, such as sandboxes and scratch orgs.
```

My guess is that we did not have source tracking activated in the master sandbox, so a refreshed sandbox from it also did not have it enabled. I also checked [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm), but it does not say anything about refreshing sandboxes from an existing sandbox. The only requirement is to create/refresh a sandbox after activating this feature which I have done.

Is it documented somewhere that we need to refresh or create a sandbox from production or does it just take a while to register and I should try refreshing again tomorrow?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. The documentation is misleading or incomplete. Refreshing or cloning a sandbox from an existing sandbox where the source control is not enabled doesn't enable source tracking on newly created sandbox